# Where to begin? - iOS "excel- like" view

Tags: ios, multidimensional-array

I'm new to iOS development. I have finished the "console" part of my app (it does what I need it to do in a Mac app without a UI), but now I have no idea on where to start for my (iOS) UI part.

Basically, I need something like a simple grid of cells (like Excel); my code reads a file, creates a dynamic (varies per file content) 2D array, and I want to show this on my UI, making each cell selectable by the user (each cell would correspond to a position in my 2D array).

Could someone point me in the right direction (even if its only the name of the classes I need to look up in apple's doc.)? I have been trying to find answers online, but it seems I'm not looking for it right.

In case I didn't explain myself correctly, I want something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UICollectionView` is the correct class to use for this. It allows you to create layouts with multiple rows and columns in a similar style to UITableView. You can also create your own custom layouts if the default one does not do what you need.